# Why NA^0 returns 1 and not NA?

Tags: r

How can I make it that R return to NA^0 = NA

```
NA*0 = NA
NA^0 = 1
NA^0.0000001 = NA
```

Comment: The provided "existing answer" will tell you _why_ this occurs, but doesn't explain how to change it, as you asked.  You can write a custom function that checks if the input is NA, and if so returns NA, otherwise raises to the supplied power.

Comment: You could redefine `^` to return `NA` if input is `NA` and return the normal value otherwise:  `'^' <- function(x,y) ifelse(is.na(x),NA,.Primitive("^")(x,y))`

Comment: The title of your question and the body of your question ask two different questions.